# Gatsby.js: I set up a css rule for body for a template but it works throughout the entire app

Tags: css, reactjs, background-image, gatsby

I set up a background image with css (background-image) in the body tag of the template so that only shows in the pages generated with it, however that's affecting all 'body's in the entire gatsby.js website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behavior. It's not a Gatsby issue. It's how React's templating/code-splitting works.

You are defining a CSS rule in your isolated CSS but it's bundled when the project is compiled (because of webpack) and because of the specificity, it affects all `body` tag. In the end, your template will be also injected into the output HTML so all the imports in it will also merge in the final output.

The easiest and most straightforward solution I think is to define a `<section>` (or another tag) just as a direct child of the `body` for each template/page you want to customize and give a specific class name to apply the CSS only to that template/page. Increasing the specificity is the easiest way to apply.

Soon, in the new Chromium version (99) we will be able to define [layered components](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/layered-components-design/) in order to enhance the specificity and improve that kind of behaviors you've described.

Comment: no reputation enough: 'Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded'